# Manipulating time on an azure vm

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a requirement to change time to a future value and run some queries on my windows server and this machine has to be in azure. I am able to change the time and run my sql queries successfully but after a restart, the azure vm is reverting back the time to default. How would I get around this and keep the manipulated time even after the VM restart OR a stop/start ?

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic (better suited for ServerFault).

Comment: Don't do it.  All the Azure infrastructure is using UTC and changing time may (or may not) have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure VM in Azure pick time from the host OS using hyper-v integration. You could try and disable that service in the VM, I'm pretty sure that is not supported, but might work. Another thing you can try - use a startup script to modify time.